# Use of type cast operator within print statement

Tags: java, casting, typecast-operator

I am having difficulty understanding why the following returns a syntax error in Java:

```
int integer1 = 5;
System.out.print("The value of integer1 is " + (String)integer1);
```

I've noticed that to bypass this error I could just create a new String variable initialized to the typecast value of integer1:

```
int integer1 = 5;
String cast = (String)integer1;
System.out.print("The value of integer1 is " + cast);
```

but this seems a bit unnecessary, especially if I'll only be displaying the value of the integer once.

Comment: you cannot cast between string and integer. both of the examples shown won't compile. why not simply use the wrapper types to convert between string and int?

Comment: @Jérôme what's done implicitly? there is no implicit cast between "int" and "string".

Comment: you say the second snippet work?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw they probably meant that in string concatenation anything will be converted to string if possible. It's not a cast, but a conversion is done implicitly.

Comment: When you are asking about an error, you should paste the exact error message in your question.

Comment: It didn't compile, I hadn't compiled it before posting the question :( I see now that the problem is with a difference in the int and String types. @Code-Apprentice, I'll keep that in mind. I think it returned an incompatible types error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only cast a primitive to another primitive or an object to a type it is an instance of. For example, you can cast a String to an Object and an int into a long. If you want an int in a string, use String.format or concatenation will handle the conversion automatically:

```
System.out.print(String.format("The value of integer1 is %d", integer1));
```

or

```
System.out.print("The value of integer1 is " + integer1);
```

BTW, An important thing in Java about primitives and casting is that you can't cast boxed primitives to other boxed types. For example if you have

```
Integer foo = 1000;
Long bar = foo;
```

You'll get a ClassCastException, but

```
int foo = 1000;
long bar = foo;
```

will work fine

To do the same with boxed vesions:

```
Integer foo = 1000;
Long bar = foo.longValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am having difficulty understanding why the following returns a
>   syntax error in Java:

```
int integer1 = 5;
String cast = (String)integer1;
System.out.print("The value of integer1 is " + cast);
```

you cannot cast from `string` to `int` or vice versa, there is no relationship in any way between the two types. In fact, none of the examples you've shown will compile.

if you want to convert between the two types, you can use these examples:

String to an integer:

```
int value = Integer.valueOf("12345");
```

or

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("12345");
```

integer to string:

```
String value = String.valueOf(12345);
```

or

```
String value = Integer.toString(12345);
```

Comment: Alternatively `String value = Integer.toString(12345);`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sure i should suggest that as well.

Comment: Is this something that's common in programming languages, for there to be a difference in the type of types?

Comment: @BrandonSweeting All programming languages have rules governing how to convert from one type to another. These rules are important to understand for whichever language you are using because it varies so widely from language to language.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you can do this instead:

```
int integer1 = 5;
System.out.print("The value of integer1 is " + integer1);
```

When you use the `+` operator to concatenate a `String` with anything else, Java automatically calls an appropriate `toString()` method for the "anything else". **This is not the same as a type cast.**